# Efficient jQuery/JS - avoiding copy-paste the same code again & again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write an efficient code in order to keep it simple & code file small, also I want to use the knowledge I hopefully get from here in future codes.

UPDATE: Just to be clear - my example is fixed "buttons" on browser window side & if you click on one of them, it takes you to div with same `ID` (look at code below).

---

**IMAGE:**

[image]

**MY CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
//Smooth Scroll Menu Links

jQuery('.div1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top-100}, 800); 
}); 

//I have to copy-paste it 1000 times & only change the ".div1" to something else

//Note that I need a solution with different class names, not "div1", "div2" etc but e.g "location", "potato", "car" etc.
```

---

**How to make this code working without writing same lines for every single div?**

There got to be a way to get `class` from item you click & then scroll to item with same name `ID`, right? Or any other way to keep codes shorter in that kind of situations - otherwise it's just copy-paste-huge-file fest.

Comment: you should add a class for each and every div and query them.. $(".scroll-elements").. if you want to use it as is, you can select all the divs that have id and start with the word "div".. like $( "div[id^='div']" )

Comment: @IliyaReyzis What if I put all "buttons" to single `<div class="buttons">` & if that `div` is clicked then use jQuery to retrieve class of `sub-div` (specific button) & use it in my code? Does that makes sense? Then there's not too much click events - only that one `div` with class `buttons`.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7gd66kr1/#run

Comment: Thanks buddy! I just tried to code something similar & jQuery is short & simple. Copy it as answer & I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each button a class so you can catch them all, than go to the element you want to scroll to by looking at the attribute of the clicked button :)

HTML

```
<div class="buttons" data-scroll="div1">div1</div>
<div class="buttons" data-scroll="div2">div2</div>
<div class="buttons" data-scroll="div3">div3</div>

<div class="content" id="div1">some content</div>
<div class="content" id="div2">some content</div>
<div class="content" id="div3">some content</div>
```

JS

```
$('.buttons').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var scrollTarget = $(this).data("scroll");
    scrollme(scrollTarget);

    function scrollme(target) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+target).offset().top}, 800);  
    }
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/7gd66kr1/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope will work with you :

```
jQuery('div').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top-100}, 800); 
});
```

note that : this function will aplay on all divs in page

Comment: I need a general solution for situations if `ID-s` are totally different like "potato", "car" or "home" - what ever `ID` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more than an unique solution. If you don't want to modify your HTML, then you need a condition to determine if the clicked element is an "active" one:

```
jQuery('div').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('class');
    var scrollto = $('#' + id);
    if(scrollto.length > 0) {
       e.preventDefault();
       jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:scrollto.offset().top-100}, 800);
    }
});
```

If you "can" modify your HTML, it's wise to add some attribute to the "active" elements (the ones that are buttons), so you know they scroll the page, or put them inside a container. The attribute you add may be a class or any other valid attribute (I recommend "rel", but might be "data" as spotted by @Iliya Reyzis , who selects by class and scrolls to "data") and select them by it:

```
<div class="div1" rel="mybutton">div1</div>
jQuery("[rel='mybutton']").on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('class');
    var scrollto = $('#' + id);
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:scrollto.offset().top-100}, 800);
});
```

Hope it helps!!